# Simbol / letter?

Tags: translation

does anyone know the meaning of this simbol / letter or whatever this is?
hahaha
any help would be appreciated
Thanks
[image]

Comment: Where does it come from?

Comment: Maybe it's an imperfectly handwritten 气?  Or maybe 亏 (or 弓 or 云).  It's hard to tell.  I'm leaning towards 云 ("cloud") as it has the correct strokes.

Comment: I am not even sure about the direction of the symbol/character you dispaly...